# How do I concatenate strings in awk, filtering out duplicate words?

Tags: arrays, unix, scripting, awk, gawk

I have a text file of the form

```
name1,name2,name3.....namen;restaurant.
```

I create an array with keys being all unique restaurants in the file.
I create a second array with keys being all the names, and value being the restaurant name.
I iterate through the second array and concatenate the key for each bucket in the second array with the bucket in the first array whose key matches the value in the second array. How can i make the concatenation disregard names that are currently already in the bucket?

Examples

```
Yan,Arnita,Rosetta,Ambrose,Jammie,Seth,Marilu; Tamarind
Myrtie,Michal,Vanesa,Louanne,Frederick,Patsy;Maxie's Supper Club
Zulma,Avril,Leisha,Jammie,Seth,Marilu;Tamarind
```

to

```
Tamarind : Zulma Avril Leisha Jammie Seth Marilu Yan Arnita Rosetta Ambrose
Maxie’s Supper Club: Myrtie Michal Vanesa Louanne Frederick Patsy
```

Comment: Give some sample input and your desired output from it.

Comment: `Yan,Arnita,Rosetta,Ambrose,Jammie,Seth,Marilu; Tamarind

Myrtie,Michal,Vanesa,Louanne,Frederick,Patsy;Maxie's Supper Club

Zulma,Avril,Leisha,Jammie,Seth,Marilu;Tamarind

to 


Tamarind : Zulma Avril Leisha Jammie Seth Marilu Yan Arnita Rosetta Ambrose

Maxie’s Supper Club: Myrtie Michal Vanesa Louanne Frederick Patsy`

Comment: Put your data in the question not in comments. It is difficult to understand what you have and what you want.

Comment: The solution you had up briefly does not provide unique output. There are still duplicate names in each restaurant output.

Comment: Have created a script that you can run as `awk` script.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will remove the duplicate names in each restaurant output:

#### Content of script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS="[,;]"}
{
  for(x = 1; x < NF; x++) {
    !tmp[$NF,$x]++ && 
    names[$NF] = (names[$NF]) ? names[$NF]" "$x : $x
  }
}
END {
  for (x in names) print x": "names[x]
}
```

#### Your file:

```
$ cat file
Yan,Arnita,Rosetta,Ambrose,Jammie,Seth,Marilu;Tamarind
Myrtie,Michal,Vanesa,Louanne,Frederick,Patsy;Maxie's Supper Club
Zulma,Avril,Leisha,Jammie,Seth,Marilu;Tamarind
```

#### Run it like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Maxie's Supper Club: Myrtie Michal Vanesa Louanne Frederick Patsy
Tamarind: Yan Arnita Rosetta Ambrose Jammie Seth Marilu Zulma Avril Leisha
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about the sort order, here's one way using `gawk`. We make use of a multi-dimensional array. Run like:

```
gawk -f ./script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {

    FS="[,;]"
}

{
    sub(/^ */,"",$NF)

    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {

        a[$NF][$i]
    }
}
END {
    for (i in a) {

        for (j in a[i]) {

            r = (r ? r : i ":") OFS j
        }

        print r
        r=""
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Tamarind: Rosetta Avril Seth Ambrose Yan Marilu Arnita Leisha Zulma Jammie
Maxie's Supper Club: Myrtie Louanne Patsy Michal Frederick Vanesa
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! I’m new to this scripting stuff. How would i make the changes neccesary to write this code in .awk script, rather than bash as it’s written now?